# Why is R writeRaster function with GTiff format so slow?

Tags: raster, r, error

I've downloaded a [countries shapefile](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip) from Natural Earth, and used it to clip [GLC2000](http://forobs.jrc.ec.europa.eu/products/glc2000/products.php) raster using Brazil's border as the mask (in R).

```
setwd('~/R/GLC2000')
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
glc <- raster('glc2000_v1_1')
pa <- readOGR('../shp/ne_10m_admin_0_countries','ne_10m_admin_0_countries')
p <- grep('Brazil',pa$ADMIN)
p1 <- crop(glc,extent(pa[p,]))
glcP <- mask(p1,pa[p,]) # dividing the mask in crop+mask makes it much faster
dim(glcP)
plot(glcP)
writeRaster(glcP,as.character(pa@data[p,'ISO_A3']),'GTiff')
```

`dim(glcP)` gives `4369 5056    1`, which is big, but not absurdly big.

`plot(glcP)` gives the image below, which proves it worked as expected.

[image: GLC2000 - Brazil]

So why doesn't writeRaster complete its task, even hours after being issued?

I want to to this for every country in the world, that's why I'm trying to do it in R. It's easier for me than a script in, say, QGIS.

Comment: For comparison, using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/207498/36566) to save it as PNG took about 3 seconds...

Comment: Is it in memory or on disk?  `?raster::inMemory`  Write to a different physical disk, or `readAll()` first.    Also this doesn't look like a good filename for a GeoTIFF, so I'd change that rather than rely on automatic settings, and I'd check what you are actually getting from that code for it

Comment: Perhaps it is not slow but it does not work at all. Have you managed to complete the task with your script with any input geometry?

Comment: Weird. Try cropping that raster to a smaller size and seeing how long that takes to write. If a 100x100 raster takes forever, something is seriously wrong...

Comment: @Spacedman It worked fast with a 41x59 raster, though it painted the background, which is black on `plot`, with dark cyan (#009696)... Same for Haiti (319x232).

Comment: @user30184 Please see the comment above. It worked with smaller countries, but with Oman (881x1092) it doesn't work anymore (10 minutes running and nothing).

Comment: @mdsumner `raster::inMemory(glcP)` returns `TRUE` for Oman (please see the two comments above). Since it worked fine with smaller countries, I don't think it's a filename issue. And I didn't understand your last sentence ("I'd check what you are actually getting from that code for it").

Comment: good point, I meant "what are you actually getting from that code for the the filename" where "that code" is the value of `as.character(pa@data[p,'ISO_A3'])`